# capturing a function pointer in lambda

Tags: c++, math, numeric

i'm doing an analysis engine that need a list of functions and their jacobian; the latter, however is optional and could be calculated with some approximation by the former.
don't worry, it's still a c++ question

i have a main class that manage the functions and their jacobian

what i'm trying to do has this structure

```
class mat; // a matrix class
using funct_type = mat(*)(double, mat); // for a more clear code
mat jacobian(func_type, double, mat); // the approximated jacobian


// the Manager class has two std::vector<func_type> F, Fjac for storing functions
void Manager::add_function(func_type f, func_type jacobian){
    this->F.push_back(f);
    if (jacobian) this->Fjac.push_back(jacobian);
    else this->Fjac.push_back([f](double t, mat m){
        return jacobian(f, t, m);
        });
}
```

but there is some problem with the capturing of f pointer. I'm sorry if i explained badly; i'm trying to use this lambda complication because it will make the use of the manager class a lot easier without the necessity to provide a jacobian function or check the case it is not provided.

Edit:
sorry for the few details, the "some problem" is that the push_back has no overload for the argument passed, making me think that the lambda is someway not being working properly; i tried with a test lambda just like

```
[](double t, mat m){
     return mat();
}
```

and it works.

Comment: Please be more specific than "there is some problem".

Comment: You can't convert a capturing lambda into a function pointer. Store`std::function<mat(double,mat)>`.

Comment: nitpick on naming: The function type is `mat (double,mat)`. `mat(*)(double,mat)` is the type of the function pointer

Comment: Parameter `jacobian` hides function `jacobian`. Use different naming to avoid confusion.

Comment: Note that you have both `func_type` and `funct_type` in your code. Presumably you made a typo somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

For better understanding lambdas I'm using simple model. It's not accurate but give some understanding of that's going on.

```
int capturing;

auto l = [capturing_var = capturing](int arg) -> res_type { /* body*/};
// we can consider l as a struct
struct _l_ {
  res_type operator()(int arg) const {
    /* body*/
  };
  auto capturing_var = capturing;
};
```

So your:

```
this->Fjac.push_back([f](double t, mat m){
        return jacobian(f, t, m);
        });
```

tries to pass `_l_::operator()` function into `funct_type`. But it has a different signature. `_l_::operator()` is a class member function! Read about pointers to class member function in the internet and how to invoke them.

But if you using lambda without capturing it turns into different structure:

```
auto l = [](int arg) -> res_type { /* body*/};
// we can consider l as a struct
struct _l_ {
  static res_type operator()(int arg) {
    /* body*/
  };
};
```

Now `_l_::operator()` function is a *static* function. Read about static class functions in the internet. Static function can be converted into function pointer like yours.

Comment: `int capturing;` and then capture by value is UB. its a detail, but why not `int capturing = 0;`

Comment: `operator()` of the lamdba is `const`

Comment: "tries to pass _l_::operator() function into funct_type." thats not correct. Its the lambda, the function object that gets passed, not its `operator()`

Comment: so there is no way to implement this kind of behaviour capturing the f function?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number as I say it's like a model just for understanding and it's not accurate.

Comment: "Its the lambda, the function object that gets passed, not its operator()" but isn't lambda has a conversion operator to function pointer which returns `operator()`

Comment: i am just saying that making `operator()` const is a simple way to make the model less wrong